# Getting error when i am trying to use constant when importing in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on react, when i am trying to use `const` `app_url` i am getting error, in this line i am getting error `import MobileEsp from app_url+'/js/mdetect.js';` it is because of app_url, here is my full code of it, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Error :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /var/www/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/src/App.js: Unexpected token (6:22)
```

Code

```
import React from 'react';

const app_url = 'https://*******.com/';

import $ from "jquery";
import MobileEsp from app_url+'/js/mdetect.js'; 

//const App = ({ title }) =>

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!MobileEsp.DetectTierIphone() && !MobileEsp.DetectTierTablet()) {

      var LinkDownloadAppMac1 = "*****";
      var LinkDownloadAppWin1 = "******";
      switch (navigator.platform) {
        case 'MacIntel':
          $('#menu-download-link').attr('href', LinkDownloadAppMac1);
          break;
        default:
          $('#menu-download-link').attr('href', LinkDownloadAppWin1);
          break;

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message as well

Comment: In app_url you have a slash at the end and when you are importing MobileEsp you are adding another slash at the beginning '/js/mdetect.js'. Also, I don't think this is the correct way to import.

Comment: the import should always have to be at  the top , unless you are dynamically importing, and  use ES6 string literal, look at @wentjun answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a legal syntax. even in modern JavaScript/ES6 JavaScript and beyond. This is because JavaScript dependency imports have to be statically resolved.

However, you can [dynamically import](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) the dependency within your component.

For instance, you can import it within your ComponentDidMount lifecycle hook.

```
async ComponentDidMount() {
  const appUrl = 'https://*******.com/';
  const MobileEsp = await import(`${appUrl}/js/mdetect.js`);
   // do the rest here
}
```